# Pokemon go bag full!

Tags: pokemon-go

My pokemon account is saying that my bag is full but it is not full. I have plenty of room and I can collect items no bother at pokemon stops. I can't catch pokemon  as it comes up saying my bag is full.  Can you help?

Answer (score 9):

Your item limit is separate from your Pokemon limit.

You get items at Poke Stops.  You get Pokemon from catching Pokemon.

[image]